# Date constructor java

Tags: java, date

Hello I am trying to get the current date at java at a Class I created but everything fails. I've seen in many sites 
 e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/
that the date constructor has no arguments 
 e.g. `Date date = new Date();`

Now in my project I try to use it like this and I get the error

> that The constructor Date() is undefined

How is this possible? I give you the full code so far

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class Utility {


        String title;
        int ID;
        Date date;

        Utility(String t,int ID){
            this.ID=ID+1;
            title=t;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
            Date a=new Date();// I get the error here
            String date = sdf.format(a);
            System.out.print(date);


        }
}
```

I work at Eclipse IDE. Can you help me?

Comment: use java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The examples you found are for [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) while you are using [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

- `java.sql.Date`

  has two constructors

  - `Date(long date)`: Constructs a Date object using the given milliseconds time value.
  - `Date(int year, int month, int day)`: which is deprecated

  and no default `Date()` constructor.
- `java.util.Date`

  among others has a default constructor without arguments

  - `Date()`: Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.

When importing classes, Eclipse will help you fining possible candidates but always check if the first suggestion is really what you want.

Comment: **Update:** Both of these `Date` classes are now obsolete. They were supplanted by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Ex: `LocalDate.parse( "23/1/2019" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu" ) )` . Or get current date: `LocalDate.now()`.

Answer (score 12):

You are using the wrong `Date` class.

Have a look at your imports. Don't use `java.sql.Date` use `java.util.Date` instead.

Comment: Don't worry, this happens to everybody. In my IDE, I usually get java.sql.Date suggested before java.util.Date; so it happens quite frequently for me :)

Answer (score 4):

You are importing `java.sql.Date` use `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 3):

You have imported wrong class. It is `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use use java.util.Calendar as follows:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date date = c.getTime();
```

Comment: Not "you also can" but "you should"! Calendar is now the way to go and you got the upvote.

Comment: You are right. Most of its methods are deprecated. But some frameworks still uses it like java Timer.

Comment: @Lucas Note, the expression new Date() is much more performant than Calendar.getInstance().getTime(). Latter implies unnecessary timezone and field initialization. And the asker only needs the epoch time for formatting in SimpleDateFormat, so I disagree with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I measured the code running times for both (using System.nanoTime()) and using Calendar seems to be 10 times slower.

Comment: Modern comment: even better, discard both `Date` and `Calendar` as outdated and use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Get today’s date:

```
LocalDate.now()
```

Generate text representing today’s date, in your desired format:

```
LocalDate
.now()
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu" ) 
)
```

> 23/1/2019

## Details

The [answer by Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20744520/642706) is correct. You are abusing the java.sql.Date class by treating it as java.util.Date.

But the answers suggesting using java.util.Calendar questions are misguided. Both java.util.Date & Calendar are notoriously bad classes, with poor design and implementation. They are outmoded by the modern *java.time* JSR 310 classes.

Also, when working with date-time you should always think about time zone. Otherwise you'll be getting default time zone with possibly varying behavior at runtime.

### *java.time*

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

If you want a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use `LocalDate`.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).